# List<Runnable> returned from shutdownNow() can not be converted to submitted Runnable

Tags: java, shutdown, java.util.concurrent

Below is the source code of the class.

I wanted to verify how does `shutdownNow()` works for not submitted task. Problem I am getting in below code is `shutdownNow()` return `List<FutureTask>` and not `List<Runnable>` which I have submitted `List<Runnable>` containing submitted instance of `PrimeProducer` .

`In Below program I wanted to get the tasks which where not executed and their state so that I can reschedule them later. name() represents just state that I want to store.`

So I am not able to convert to submitted Task.

```
class PrimeProducer implements Runnable {
private final SynchronousQueue<BigInteger> queue;

PrimeProducer(SynchronousQueue<BigInteger> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
        queue.put(p = p.nextProbablePrime());
    } catch (InterruptedException consumed) {
        System.out.println("Safe Exit");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

}

public String name() {
    return "PrimeProducer";
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
        ExecutionException {
    PrimeProducer primeProducer = new PrimeProducer(
            new SynchronousQueue<BigInteger>());//SynchronousQueue just to ensure it put is blocking
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    executorService.submit(primeProducer);
    executorService.submit(primeProducer);
    List<Runnable> list = executorService.shutdownNow();
    //PrimeProducer producer = (PrimeProducer) list.get(0);// Class Cast
                                                            // Exception
    FutureTask<PrimeProducer> futureTask = (FutureTask<PrimeProducer>) list
            .get(0);
            System.out.println(futureTask.isDone());//Prints false
    futureTask.get().name();//futureTask-->PrimeProducer get() hangs.


}
}
```

**Problematic Lines**

```
//PrimeProducer producer = (PrimeProducer) list.get(0);// Class Cast
                                                            // Exception
 FutureTask<PrimeProducer> futureTask = (FutureTask<PrimeProducer>) list
            .get(0);
 futureTask.get().name();//futureTask-->PrimeProducer get() hangs.
```

Comment: I would check `isDone()` first as I suspect all the tasks returned by `shutdownNow()` will never run and never be set.

Comment: Peter was faster :) Plus: I would always null-check the result of a get().

Comment: @PeterLawrey isDone() is false. In current program I know there will be always one thread that will be left out so I have made some assumptions.

Comment: I have still not understood, what you actually want to do here ... Is that just an experiment to check what shutdownNow does? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow() is quite clear about that.

Comment: Are you sure the list contains one and only one `Runnable`? I believe you get a `ClassCastException` _because_ the first `Runnable` in the list _is not_ a `PrimeProducer` (BTW a `FutureTask` _is_ a `Runnable` as the former class implements the latter.).

Comment: Yes. I have updated question to accommodate comments

Comment: What is the runtime type of the `Runnable` in the list?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez It is `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`

Comment: Why FutureTask? shutdownNow returns a List of Runnables, which may pretty probably be PrimeProducers. So just check the RuntimeType, cast and print the name. EDIT: Forget it. I didn't read the commented part there.

Comment: According to the docs, FutureTask.get() waits for the computation to complete, but if you've shut down the thread, that's never going to happen. Try the other form of get, the one with a timeout.

Comment: Have you tried ''execute'' instead of ''submit'' ? shutdownNow should then return a List of Runnables with a runtimetype of your PrimeProducer

Comment: @Fildor Spot on. That is the reason. Now I will dig dipper can you please add it as answer.

Comment: @AmitD: ok, so I guess that this `FutureTask` is actually "wrapping" your PrimeProducer `Runnable`. From what I know of the implementation, you cannot get access to it from the `FutureTask`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "execute" instead of "submit".

Answer (score 0):

This behavior happens because there is difference between how `execute` and `submit` handles task that are submitted.

`execute` method directly uses `Runnable command` which is passed to it where as `submit` create `RunnableFuture` and call `execute`

```
 RunnableFuture<Object> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
```