# Executor Service issue with Submit and ShutdownNow with RunnableException

Tags: java, executorservice

This question is Related to [List returned from shutdownNow() can not be converted to submitted Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493449/listrunnable-returned-from-shutdownnow-can-not-be-converted-to-submitted-run)

**Problem definition**

I want to get runtime exception from `Runnable`and which I can get only using `submit() call which returns me Future<?>`.

If I use `Submit` I loose on the functionality which is provided by `execute`. As I will no longer able to use `shutdownNow()` to track not started threads.

So Is this true

**If I want to catch runnable exception from my task I will never be able to use shutdownnow to find out not started task.**

Comment: Partly for this reason I use `shutdown()` instead which doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `execute()` together with Future by using a custom subclass of FutureTask (which is a Runnable).  for most Executors, calling `submit()` just wraps the Runnable/Callable with a FutureTask under the hood.  In you custom subclass of FutureTask, keep a reference to the underlying Runnable/Callable and expose a method for returning it.  then, when you call `shutdownNow()`, the returned Runnables should be instances of your custom FutureTask.  (it's annoyting that you need to subclass FutureTask to be able to get at the underlying task, but that's the way it is).

Comment: Seems not possible even though I pass My Class object `submit()` wraps to `FutureTask<T>` now there is no way to get object form this.

Comment: @AmitD - why are you calling `submit()`?  you should be calling `execute()`.

Comment: Errr. My Bad.It works I checked it. But still problem remains how to get the RuntimeException thrown from first thread?

Comment: @AmitD - you can get any thrown exceptions from the future, like normal

Comment: Yes It works properly. I was using single task instance. It should be Future task per runnable. Thanks for your time and answer. `Down voter please remove the down vote `